# transform my query to get columns of two tables at time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have mysqli query that do my job correctly when counting number of rows only, now with the same query i want get appropriated column values.

Here my query:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("
SELECT *
  FROM verify 
 WHERE user_id = '$uid' 
    AND verified = 1
   AND id NOT IN (SELECT verified_id FROM verified WHERE user_id='$uid' AND banned = '0' GROUP BY verified_id)
");
$infos = $query->fetch_assoc();
$counting = $query->num_rows;
```

How to get infos inside `VERIFIED` table ? `VERIFY` table's infos got successfully.

**EDIT**

I want get for example column value of the `VERIFIED` table like: `$infos["email"];`

For now i can get only column values of `VERIFY` table.

Comment: I don't know what the "appropriated [sic] column values are".  Do you?  If so, you should explain in the question.  Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Done, you can check.

Comment: is it mean, you want to get 'email' string or the value inside email?

Comment: I want get `Email` returned from the query contained in the `COLUMN EMAIL` inside `VERIFIED` table.

Comment: Think, I've finally got what you want. Add your inner join try here, so it would be easier for me to write proper statement

Comment: How can you expect values from the `verified` table when you have a `where` condition saying you don't want to list anything that corresponds with a record in `verified`?

Comment: To OP - please respond to @trincot as your *correct* query goes against desired result. In fact, some data from both tables may help illustrate needs.

Comment: @trincot my question is what you are clarifing ! i want get the result you are speaking about.

Comment: I was not speaking about a result, but the contradiction in your question. I cannot help you with that, I am afraid. Can you update your question with sample data for the two tables, and show which result you want to get for that sample data?